# How to prove that EMPTY is not recursively enumerable?

Tags: turing-machines, computability

I need to prove that the following language is not recursively enumerable, while its complement is recursively enumerable:
$L := \{w \in \{0,1\}^* |$ TM $M$ with $w = \langle $ M $\rangle$ does not accept any input $\}$.

Should I use a reduction from the halting problem in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [the extension of Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem#An_analogue_of_Rice%27s_theorem_for_recursive_sets) to prove that $L\notin RE$